# Use vi to replace everything between two known strings on multiple lines

Tags: search

I need to replace the first number that comes after `AAA,` with `0.05`
So this:

```
AAA,1.25,2020-08-30
BB,0.1,2020-08-30
CCC,1.6,2020-08-30
DDDD,1.5,2020-08-31
EE,1.75,2020-08-31
FFF,0.05,2020-08-31
AAA,0.25,2021-01-31
GG,0.1,2021-01-31
```

would become

```
AAA,0.05,2020-08-30
BB,0.1,2020-08-30
CCC,1.6,2020-08-30
DDDD,1.5,2020-08-31
EE,1.75,2020-08-31
FFF,0.05,2020-08-31
AAA,0.05,2021-01-31
GG,0.1,2021-01-31
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do that for you:

```
:%s/\v^AAA,([^,]+)/AAA,0.05/
```

Explanation:

- `%s/{pattern}/{string}/`: for each line in the whole file (`%`) **s**ubstitute a match of `{pattern}` with `{string}` ([`:h :s`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute))
- `\v`: one of vim's four regex modes ([`:h /magic`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic))
- `^AAA,([^,]+)`: match lines starting with `AAA,` followed by one or more characters that are not a comma
- `AAA,0.05`: the string to replace the match with

Comment: You can also use `:%s/^AAA,\zs[^,]\+/0.05/`, which avoids the need for grouping in the match and repeating the beginning of the match in the replacement.

Comment: @filbranden Thanks, I didn't know about `\zs` and `\ze`.

Comment: Also `:g/^AAA/norm! f,lct,0.05`